# Swift iOS how to add WebViews in a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, uiwebview

I am curious if it's possible to add UIWebViews by code rather than dragging and dropping them into the story board.

The reason being is because my app is going to download an object from a database which is an array of strings containing urls to different youtube videos.

This object will be modified by the admin throughout time so the amount of youtube urls in it will be different and unknown by me/the coder.

I want to have a UIWebView display each youtube video inside a scroll pane.

However since I don't know how many UIWebViews will be necessary to add how could I take the size of the array object and somehow in a for loop add in the UIWebViews to the scroll pane with the specified url from the array object?

Comment: If you play many videos in a time,I think it will crash because of overflow.

Comment: What would be the best method of displaying the videos in a list with thumbnail and title of video then so that when clicked they can play full screen without crashing?

Comment: Year，or display a few gifs.